# How to add additional css class to dynamic sidebar ( not widget ) in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

What I'm trying is to add an additional class to my custom registered sidebar to frontend. From [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) I can add a class when I'm registering a sidebar but it will show in admin area not on the frontend:

```
<?php register_sidebar( $args ); ?>

<?php $args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',    // ID should be LOWERCASE  ! ! !
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' ); ?>
```

> class - CSS class to assign to the Sidebar in the Appearance -> Widget admin page. This class will only appear in the source of the WordPress Widget admin page. It will not be included in the frontend of your website. Note: The value "sidebar" will be prepended to the class value. For example, a class of "tal" will result in a class value of "sidebar-tal". (default: empty).

Is it possible to add additional css class to dynamic sidebar without adding it through template?

Comment: Well, I would follow the steps in the codex. Why would you need that?

Comment: I'm just curious. It would be good if there is an option on the fly